# What is the proper syntax to execute a google web search from my Android 2.2 application?

Tags: android, search

Working on an Android application, which needs to execute a google web search from within a ListView activity and display the results in that List View.

Such search would always be for the same "static" subject, such as "...bowling alleys in Chicago...", so, the user will not be entering any search criteria.

What is the proper way to accomplish this, please?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to display in the list? You'll have to do the search and parse the html. http://www.google.com/search?q=bowling+alleys+in+chicago

Answer (score 0):

I would just URL-encode the search request, create an URL using the official Google Search API and open this in a browser, which would be:

```
try {
    String search = "your search here";
    String encodedSearch = URLEncoder.encode(search, "UTF-8");
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com/search?q=" + encodedSearch)));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // should not happen, maybe add some Log.e() here
}
```

Have fun! :-)

**EDIT:** Oh, I just answered too quickly and now I read that you want to display the search results in a ListView. So basically you will need an API key then and use the official search API by Google. More information and documentation here:
http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html